# cloudant local edition, remote dashboard

Tags: cloudant

I'm doing some prototyping with Cloudant Local Edition (1.0.0.5 on Ubuntu 14.04, if it matters).

With a vanilla install, the Cloudant dashboard app runs on the same server as the Cloudant node. I'm looking for a way to use the dashboard to connect to a Cloudant instance on another server. In other words, I have Cloudant nodes A, B, and C. From my desktop browser, I can connect to each dashboard as http://A/dashboard.html, or http://B/dashboard.html. What I am looking for is a way to connect to A/dashboard.html (perhaps on a different port) and be able to connect to A or B.

I've been scouring documentation and also poking around at lots of files in my Cloudant Local Edition installed software. So far, no joy.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are nodes A, B, and C clustered? If they are, there should be a load balancer in front of them that also runs the dashboard.  You can find info about the load balancer installation in Cloudant Local docs.

If not, then I think what you're trying to do is impossible, unfortunately. The dashboard isn't a management console for multiple Cloudant installations.